# How get recursively parent children names

Tags: javascript, jquery

I try to get all children names to parent all of them. I`m create a tree in:

```
GUI.prototype.buildTree = function(elements, parentId){
    var response = [];
    for(var elem in elements){
        if(elements[elem]['parent'] == parentId){
            var childrens = this.buildTree(elements, elements[elem]['id']);
            if(childrens.length > 0){
                elements[elem]['childrens'] = childrens;
            }
            response.push(elements[elem]);
        }
    }
    return response;
};
```

My input from buildTree method looks like:

```
[{
    "id" : 'x',
    "parent" : 0,
    "childrens" : [{
        "id" : 'y',
        "parent" : "x",
        "childrens" : [{
            "id" : 'z',
            "parent" : "y"
        }]
    }]
}]
```

and I would like to output like:

```
[{
    "id": "x", 
    "childrenNames": ["y", "z"]
}]
```

The best opion could be do it in buildTree method but I dont know how. But for more easly i think should be create another method for that.

I ask for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This proposal visits all nodes and gets all children for the node.

```js
function getChildren(array) {
    var result = [];
    array.forEach(function iter(a) {
        var children = [];
        result.push({ id: a.id, children: children });
        this.push(a.id);
        if (Array.isArray(a.children)) {
            a.children.forEach(iter, children);
            Array.prototype.splice.apply(this, [this.length, 0].concat(children));
        }
    }, []);
    return result;
}

var data = [{ id: 'x', parent: 0, children: [{ id: 'y', parent: "x", children: [{ id: 'z', parent: "y" }] }] }];

console.log(getChildren(data));
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```